# How to call a property declared in the constructor from the State class in StatefullWidget

Tags: flutter, dart, oop

I'm doing a little experiment with `StateFulWidget` constructor like below.

```
class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  const Foo.double({super.key,ValueChanged<double>? onchaged}) ;
  const Foo.int({super.key,ValueChanged<int>? onchaged}) ;

  @override
  State<Foo> createState() => _FooState();
}

class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // how can i call the onchaged here ?
    onchaged?.call(22);
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

and when to use `Foo` widget, I can specify the `onchaged` type:

```
Foo.int(onchaged: (val){
  // runType val should be integer
}),
```

```
Foo.double (onchaged: (val){
  // runType val should be double
}),
```

I don't want to make it a generic widget, since I only need `double` and `int`.
Is it possible to use `onchaged` inside `_FooState` class?

I **cant** use `widget.onchaged` because it's not declared as property of `Foo`.
and if I declare it as property, I **cant** specify the type.

is it possible? or maybe there is another better approach?

TIA

Comment: for example you can create in `Foo` class `ValueChanged<double>? _onDoubleChanged` and `ValueChanged<int>? _onIntChanged` and assign them in your two constructors

Comment: @pskink, Yes, that's how I use separate properties in my widgets currently. And I'm just experimenting, if possible, I can reduce a lot of my properties. actually, there are several properties that need to be specified `int` or `double`.

Comment: and cannot you use `ValueChanged<num> onChanged`?

Comment: also already use `num` type as default.